# What's the difference complementizing between with gerund-participle and to-infinitive?

Tags: complementation

> They would have felt sorry for Hagrid when the time came for him to
>   say good-bye to Norbert if they hadn't been so worried about what they
>   had to do. It was a very dark, cloudy night, and they were a bit
>   **late arriving at Hagrid's hut** because they'd had to wait for Peeves to get out of their way in the entrance hall, where he'd been
>   playing tennis against the wall. (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

It seems that ‘late’ is complementized far more with ‘arriving’[A] than ‘to arrive’[B]. What’s the difference between the two in meaning?

[image]

Comment: I think it's likely that 'a bit late' is an adverbial going in the mid-position -- `they were arriving` + `a bit late` = **`'they were a bit late arriving'`**. _'a bit late to arrive...'_ would mean _'it is already late to arrive at the hut'_, which seems to make less sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and they were a bit late **arriving** at Hagrid's hut because . .

'arriving..' here starts **a participle clause** to describe an event simultaneous with 'were a bit late'.

> and they were a bit late **as they were arriving** at Hagrid's hut because . .

The participle clause can be converted to a adverbial clause as above.

> We are a bit late **to arrive** there on time.

'to arrive' is an adverbial clause to express a purpose. 
'in order to arrive' can be used instead.